# Solving non-homogeneous first order Linear ODE $y'' + y\tan x = \sec x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do i solve this using the method of undetermined coefficients?
$$y'' + y\tan x = \sec x$$
I know how to solve it using other methods but i couldn't find the particular solution while trying the method of undetermined coefficients. I saw a similar question but without $\tan(x)$, does having it makes this solvable using the method of undetermined coefficients?

Comment: As a matter of interest: should your first order ODE not be

$$y' + y \tan(x) = \sec(x)?$$

(Otherwise it is too much for Mathematica to handle.)

In which case, you can do it, but it may be hard to guess — did you find the homogeneous solution ($=0$)? That's always a good start

Comment: The method of undetermined coefficients only applies to linear ODE with constant coefficients and a special structure of the forcing terms, and in extension of that, in the modified equivalent form also to Euler-Cauchy DE. In this task with non-constant coefficients, the method is not applicable.

Comment: @GoodBoy yes indeed the original question was that. I thought if someone could show me for the order two would be even better. Yes, homogeneous solution is fairly easy to find, it is sec(x) that gives me trouble to find the particular solution.

Comment: Firstly, I think you ought to edit your answer: your title is perhaps a little misleading: also, $y=\sec(x)$ is a solution to

$$y′-y\tan(x)=\sec(x),$$

not the one you wrote. Moreover, it is very, very easy to make ODEs unsolvable (the solution exists, but can't be derived using your desired methods) which I think you did by adding $y''$.

Assuming it's 

$$y′-y\tan(x)=\sec(x),$$

let $L(y) = y' - y\tan(x).$ You've shown $L(\sec(x)) = 0$, so why not try $x\sec(x)$?